# Two scanf functions but one reads a different value

Tags: c, string, decimal, scanf

I'm struggling in letting the program read the variable total that was  previously input after asking for the input for the variable month. The total is always 28257 and I don't know why.

I found out using `" %c"` on line 11 works, but I would like to know why `"%s"` doesn't.

```
    #include <stdio.h>  
    int main(void) { 

    int total; 
    char month;
    float sales;

    printf ("Enter total amount collected (-1 to quit): ");
    scanf("%d", &total);
    printf("Enter name of month: ");
    scanf("%s", &month);
    printf("total collections : $ %d\n", total);
    sales = (total/1.09);
    printf("sales : $ %.2f\n", sales);
    printf("county sales tax: $ %.2f\n", sales * 0.05);
    printf("state tax: $ %.2f\n", sales*0.04);
    printf("total sales tax collected: $ %.2f\n", sales *0.05 + sales *0.04);
    return 0;   }
```

Comment: `char month;  scanf("%s", &month);` is a problem.  Research `scanf()` and what is expected with `"%s"`.  `"%s"` wants to form a _string_  ( a null character terminate sequence of characters).  `char` is too small.

Comment: You are reading a "string" into a single char.

Answer (score 0):

you declared **month** as character, so you should use **%c** for input. **%s** is used for input character array. and before **scanf("%c", &month);**, also use **getchar();**.

- getchar();
- scanf("%c", &month);